# Code not printing parent process statements

Tags: c, process, operating-system, zombie-process

I am running the following code:

```
// A C program to demonstrate Zombie Process. 
// Child becomes Zombie as parent is sleeping
// when child process exits.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    // Fork returns process id
    // in parent process
    pid_t child_pid = fork();

    // Parent process 
    if (child_pid > 0)
        {printf("in parent process");
        sleep(50);
        }

    // Child process
    else       
        {   printf("in child process");
            exit(0);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

And get following output:

```
$main
in child process
```

I am running the code here: http://tpcg.io/6ZccnX

Why is the statement "in parent process" not printing?

Comment: Because you `sleep(50);`. The unit is second, it's a long time. Change to `sleep(1);` everything is ok.

Comment: You might want to use `printf("in parent process\n");`, or `printf("in parent process"); fflush(stdout);`.

Comment: Output to standard output is usually buffered until a newline occurs.  Put the newline at the end of the outputs you want to see.  (Even then, if you pipe the output to another program or redirect to a file, just a newline won't necessarily force the output; you might need to use `fflush(stdout)` as well — or instead, but the newlines are a good idea in general).

Answer (score 1):

the `stdout` is usually not flushed until a new line has occured
I've tested the following and both options work as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    // Fork returns process id
    // in parent process
    pid_t child_pid = fork();

    // Parent process 
    if (child_pid > 0)
    {
        /*option one: put '\n' at the end of the print to flush it */
        printf("in parent process\n");
        /*option two: flush all the available streams after print*/
//      printf("in parent process");
//      fflush(NULL);
        sleep(50);
    }

    // Child process
    else       
    {   printf("in child process");
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```